# Schottky Diodes in parallel

Tags: schottky

I was looking at a reference design and I saw a symbol I didn't recognize:

[image: ref design]

So I looked up the part. It's a dual Schottky rectifier like this:

[image]

What is the purpose of having two diodes in parallel in this case?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reference design? Some kind of high side FET driver?

Comment: You needed one, they come in pairs, why waste the other?

Comment: If the two diodes are in the same package, as they are here, you get more current capability by paralleling them up.  Also as @BrianDrummond points out why waste the other diode.  Don't parallel diodes in different packages however: you can't guarantee they will share the current equally.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.richtek.com/product_detail.jsp?s=493) a link to the RT8105, how about a link to your reference design?

Comment: Maybe just to get a bit more maximum current?

Comment: I can't give out the entire reference design. But it's the power control section of the design and is very similar what is in the RT8105 except for the diodes.

Comment: I thought it was a bad idea to put diodes in parallel because of current hogging (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_runaway). Would that not apply in this instance?

Comment: Re: thermal runaway, if they are in the same package it can only go so far.  If these diodes are on the same piece of Silicon, then it's even better. (less of a worry)

Comment: If those are schottky diodes, that's a shitty schematic drawing. They need the proper cross-bar symbol.

Comment: Schottky diodes tend to be rather leaky- this should not necessarily be SOP if not required- it obviously will double the leakage current.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current is split between two junctions, thus slightly reducing thermal dissipation on each one and improving reliability/MTBF. 
Since the diodes are in the same package, the risk of unbalanced current is likely to be very low, so considerations about paralleling discrete diodes don't apply.

Furthermore, SOT23 double diodes seem to be very common and somewhat standard in larger firms (thus less expensive). Given that connecting together anodes of a double diode doesn't involve a significant increase in the probability of failure, it makes sense to *do* so instead of *not*.

However, it is important to note that such approach leads to *double* leakage current. This has to be considered for applications where leakage current can raise any problem.

Take a look at this German forum topic, about BAT54C (very similar to BAR43C, indeed): [Warum zwei parallele Dioden?](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/221016) ([Google translation](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=german&tl=en&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mikrocontroller.net%2Ftopic%2F221016&edit-text=&act=url))

Answer (score 0):

Diodes shall never be put in parallel, unless they are in the same package. (More or less true) :

**From a thermal perspective:**
Having both of them in the same package guarantee the differents junctions are at the same temperature. The risk of unbalanced current, is still present, but every rise in temperature of one diode will impact other one. Which make a thermal runaway of one diode less likely.

**From a current perspective:**
Whit that said, you shall never put diodes in parallel to increase the max current. Max current shall still be less that the individual maximum current of one diode. Because even in the same package diode can have different forward voltage, meaning an unequal current spread.

**If the diodes are not in the same package :**
The false theory, is that the current will be spread accros the two diodes.

In fact what will happen is that the diode whith the lesser forward voltage with let pass more current. Provoking a rise in temperature, this rise in temperature cause the forward voltage to decrease even more due to the negative thermal coefficient of diode junctions. This is thermal runaway, where the diode will be destroyed due do this positive feedback loop.

This is explained partly in the following document : **AN4381 Application note**

Comment: "*... the diode whith the lesser forward voltage with let pass more current.*" So with two adequately rated parallel diodes you get a possible improvement in reduction of forward voltage drop. As pointed out in Cerv's answer, because they are both in the same package, both made on the same die in the same batch they will be very closely matched and "current hogging" will not be a problem.  "*The false theory, is that the current will be spread across the two diodes.*" It's not false. The current will be spread - just not perfectly evenly - although very closely in this case.

Comment: @Transistor are you sure about the single die ? From what I read, e.g. the ubiquitous dual NPN transistors contain two discrete co-packaged transistors. And they sell special matched version.